# How to interact with private eth network with web3js

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am developing voting daap for institute and I want to interact with my private eth network. I can't use any testnet because accounts are limited there. I want around 5-6k accounts that's why I preferring to the private eth network. I cannot find anything so that I interact with nodes from website as infura is not supporting private networks now.

Comment: Since it is a private network the only option is to ask the owners of the network to provide access. If you are managing the network you can use a geth instance to provide RPC endpoint.

Comment: I am managing the network but cannot find any proper documentation to connect it